# how to refresh icon after change file association in XP?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++, windows-xp, windows-shell

I have tried to change file association of .htm file in XP, and here is how I did it:

1. Change the associated registry key values.
2. Call `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0)` to refresh the icon.

After doing these, I double clicking the .htm file, and it is opened by the browser I expected. But the icon on the desktop is not changed into the new one(e.g. from IE to Chrome).
However, if I restart explorer.exe, the icon changed to the correct one.

Can anyone please tell me how to refresh the icon on desktop after changing the file association ?

Any replies from you will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> SHChangeNotify, SHCNE_GLOBALEVENTS, SHCNF_IDLIST OR SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT
>   OR SHCNF_NOTIFYRECURSIVE, 0, 0

Change OR to whatever OR is in your language works for me.

Or change

> SHCNE_GLOBALEVENTS to SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED

Comment: impossible, that is what I use in my File Extension editor and nobody has trouble with it.  What OS?

Comment: sorry Gunner, your solution works, it's the regsitry value that I add make this looks mess. I delete some values that are useless and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send notification about changed environment, this may work out:

```
DWORD result2 = 0;
LRESULT result = SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
    (LPARAM)_T("Environment"), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &result2);
```